Could not upload to pypi: 400 Bad Request from https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
I have build a python package and prepared to make a distributable using twine using python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel. This created two files in the dist directory:
PACKAGENAME-0.1.1-py3-none-any.whl
PACKAGENAME-0.1.1.tar.gz

The setup.py script has been configured as:
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
    name='PACKAGE NAME',
    version='0.1.1',
    author='blackthorne18',
    description='Testing package',
    url='GITHUBURL', #This URL links to a public repository on github of the package directory
    py_modules=['entrypoint', 'runscript'],
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=[requirements],
    python_requires='>=3.10',
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.10",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
    entry_points='''
        [console_scripts]
        PACKAGE=entrypoint:main
    '''
)

The authentication for my pypi account has been setup in $HOME/.pypirc using token based authentication. I am able to create and upload my package to test.pypi without any issues.
$ twine upload --repository testpypi dist/* --verbose

Uploading PACKAGENAME-0.1.1.tar.gz
100% ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 27.8/27.8 kB • 00:00 • 29.3 MB/s
INFO     Response from https://test.pypi.org/legacy/:                                                                             
         200 OK                                                                                                                   
INFO     <html>                                                                                                                   
          <head>                                                                                                                  
           <title>200 OK</title>                                                                                                  
          </head>                                                                                                                 
          <body>                                                                                                                  
           <h1>200 OK</h1>                                                                                                        
           <br/><br/>                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
          </body>                                                                                                                 
         </html>                                                                                                                  
View at:
https://test.pypi.org/project/PACKAGENAME/0.1.1/

If I try to upload the same distribution to the pypi repository, I get the following error:
$ twine upload dist/* --verbose

Uploading PACKAGENAME-0.1.1-py3-none-any.whl
100% ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 27.9/27.9 kB • 00:00 • 16.0 MB/s
INFO     Response from https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/:                                                                           
         400 Bad Request                                                                                                          
INFO     <html>                                                                                                                   
          <head>                                                                                                                  
           <title>400 Bad Request</title>                                                                                         
          </head>                                                                                                                 
          <body>                                                                                                                  
           <h1>400 Bad Request</h1>                                                                                               
           The server could not comply with the request since it is either malformed or otherwise incorrect.<br/><br/>            
         POST body may not contain duplicate keys                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                  
          </body>                                                                                                                 
         </html>                                                                                                                  
ERROR    HTTPError: 400 Bad Request from https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/                                                          
         Bad Request      

If I run twine check dist/* on the package, it says both files in dist/ have PASSED the check.
I presume the main error message is POST body may not contain duplicate keys but I don't really know what that means. How do I fix this?
Versions:
python version 3.10
twine version 4.0.1 (importlib-metadata: 5.0.0, keyring: 23.11.0, pkginfo: 1.8.3, requests: 2.28.1, requests-toolbelt: 0.10.1,
urllib3: 1.26.12)


This problem has potentially been fixed via https://github.com/pypi/warehouse/pull/16759. Could you please try uploading again today and see if you still have the problem?

I struggled with this error today too.
Make sure you haven't already uploaded the package before with the current version. Even if you deleted the package, pypi will store the meta-data in order to avoid potential conflicts.
The solution is to bump the version, just to make sure this is not the cause for the error you are seeing.

I think this issue is caused by the file already existing on pypi but the usual error message that the file already exists is being suppressed by a recent pypi PR. If you can test this is the case in your instance you may want to comment on the PR confirming you're getting an unhelpful error message when the file exists.

It looks like a fix has now been made https://github.com/pypi/warehouse/pull/16759.

Yes I can confirm it’s fixed for me.
