GitHub Actions fails to publish distribution package to test PyPI
I've been following the tutorial for automating the push of latest packages on pip from here. I'm trying to do it on Test PyPI for now.
My YAML configure release.yml file is:
name: Publish Python  distribution  to PyPI and TestPyPI

on: push

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build distribution 
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4
    - name: Set up Python
      uses: actions/setup-python@v5
      with:
        python-version: "3.11"
    - name: Install pypa/build
      run: >-
        python3 -m
        pip install
        build
        --user
    - name: Install dependencies and Run tests
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        python -m pip install .
        python -m pip install -r test/requirements.txt
        pytest test
    - name: Build a binary wheel and a source tarball
      run: python3 -m build
    - name: Store the distribution packages
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
      with:
        name: python-package-distributions
        path: dist/

  publish-to-testpypi:
    name: Publish Python  distribution  to TestPyPI
    needs:
    - build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    environment:
      name: testpypi
      url: https://test.pypi.org/p/mypkg

    permissions:
      id-token: write

    steps:
    - name: Download all the dists
      uses: actions/download-artifact@v4
      with:
        name: python-package-distributions
        path: dist/
    - name: Publish package distributions to TestPyPI
      uses: pypa/gh-action-pypi-publish@release/v1
      with:
        repository-url: https://test.pypi.org/legacy/

I have also followed to add the trusted publishers from the PyPI website so there is no need to specify the API tokens apparently.
After pushing a new commit I get the following error:
ERROR    HTTPError: 400 Bad Request from https://test.pypi.org/legacy/          
         Bad Request 


EDIT : By running the verbose argument to true the error becomes a bit more precise :
INFO     dist/torchdde-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (35.2 KB)                         
INFO     dist/torchdde-0.1.0.tar.gz (23.1 KB)                                   
INFO     password set by command options                                        
INFO     username: __token__                                                    
INFO     password: <hidden>                                                     
Uploading torchdde-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
INFO     Response from https://test.pypi.org/legacy/:                           
         400 Bad Request                                                        
INFO     <html>                                                                 
          <head>                                                                
           <title>400 Bad Request</title>                                       
          </head>                                                               
          <body>                                                                
           <h1>400 Bad Request</h1>                                             
           The server could not comply with the request since it is either      
         malformed or otherwise incorrect.<br/><br/>                            
         POST body may not contain duplicate keys                               
                                                                                
                                                                                
          </body>                                                               
         </html>                                                                
ERROR    HTTPError: 400 Bad Request from https://test.pypi.org/legacy/          
         Bad Request     

As of now I haven't found any solutions, do you have any recommendations?
I'd like also to note that my current master is on version 0.1.0 and that the first PyPI test was done successfully by doing the CLIs with a version 0.0.1 so i'm not sure that the version bumping is the problem here.

Seems a popular error today: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79001452/could-not-upload-to-pypi-400-bad-request-from-https-upload-pypi-org-legacy

This seems to be close to his issue. I did some digging and I made sure that I'm deploying on a new version of the package so it seems we are on two different issues.  Thanks for the thread.

This has potentially been fixed by https://github.com/pypi/warehouse/pull/16759. Could you try again today and see if things now work for you?

Yes indeed this was fixed with the latest PR

This issue was resolved with https://github.com/pypi/warehouse/issues/16756 .
